# Calling setImageResource from AsyncTask multiple times

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview

Good day everyone.

I'm working with **AsyncTasks** and calling `publishProgress();` from `doInBackground()` method. I'm pretty sure there's no error until here.

I need to change an ImageView's source, e.g. in every 3 seconds from `onProgressUpdate()` method.

If i only do this;

```
        agiz.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
```

initial image successfully changes to image1.

But if i try to do this (which is my goal actually)

```
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
```

imageView **WAITS 6 SECONDS, THEN** turns to image3, without showing image2.

What am i missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What has this code to do with an AsyncTask?

Comment: @greenapps I'm suspecting that onProgressUpdate() method of the AsyncTack has a delay for updating UI. This would be the only logic explanation of the bug i'm facing.

Comment: You still did not tell what your code has to do with an AsyncTask or onProgressUpdate(). We cannot see that here. Pleas post a better example.

Comment: `mageView instantly turns to image3,`. No. That would take at least six seconds.

Comment: @greenapps The problem isn't about how much time it takes, or what were my intentions to use AsyncTasks. The problem is, why does this code skips image2. Can we please stay on subject ?

Comment: Please rephrase your problem as `instantly` would not be after six seconds.

Comment: @greenapps Hope you're happy.

Comment: Thanks. You can conclude that the GUI only gets updated after your code (on the main thread) is finished. You could see the same with a TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) method. It will be more readable and effective, because this method works in UI thread.

```
imageView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
    }}
,3000);

imageView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
    }}
,6000);

imageView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
    }}
,9000);
```

**Explantation your problem.**

I suppose that you block UI thread. `Thread.sleep()` method block current thread immediatly without waiting while your imageView was repainted, so you getting a `lock` result.

Comment: This code has some syntax errors. You should write Runnable(){  and remove the paranthesis before 3000, i fixed them and it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @EmreAcar i have no IDE on hands, so if you edit correctly my answer i will be gratefull

Comment: This answer is correct. The repaint is only done when the program is back in the event queue which is not possible when the thread is sleeping.